# Converting XMLHttpRequest to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest, restsharp

I've now spent some time trying to get the JavaScript below working in my API (c#).

I run perfectly in JavaScript, but I get access denied as a response in my c# code.

JS :

```js
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById('KundeListing').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "https://plus.dnb.com/v1/search/typeahead?searchTerm=Wal&countryISOAlpha2Code=US");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.send();
```

But When trying using`RestSharp`; I am getting errors

> 'You are not currently authorized to access this product'

```c#
    public string Get(string Token)
       { 
           var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://plus.dnb.com/v1/search/typeahead?searchTerm=Wal&countryISOAlpha2Code=US");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };
            request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer  " + Token);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            return response.ToString();
    }
```

---

Comment: Your headers seem slightly different from you JS example. Not that it should be causing a problem I'm just asking if that is on purpose or not

Comment: Of course it should be 
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: there should be only one space in "Bearer  "

Comment: Oh My god.... You're right..... Maybe I need glasses :-D HaHa .... Thanx

Comment: The content type is only needed when sending the request body. You aren't sending any JSON to the server. It's not what creates issues as you already figured out, just a side note.